# Why do I have a `SQLITE_AUTOINDEX` index for my primary key? I thought that's what a table already was

Tags: sqlite

I've got this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hash (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  base32 TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX hash_base32 ON hash(base32);
```

and `sqlite3_analyzer` gives me this:

```
*** Page counts for all tables and indices separately *************************

HASH_BASE32....................................... 15          14.3% 
SQLITE_AUTOINDEX_HASH_1........................... 15          14.3% 
HASH.............................................. 14          13.3%
```

My question is: Isn't `HASH` (the table) already the btree that serves as the index on the primary key `id`? Why is there a separate `SQLITE_AUTOINDEX_HASH_1`?  I'd like my db to be that much smaller if one of these is redundant.

Thanks!

Comment: Index != primary key?

Comment: @TomYan I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: It's a hint, not a question.

Comment: @TomYan I'm not sure what you're hinting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer at the sqlite forum: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/bb62e57c5b

tl;dr: I was creating two indexes on the `base32` column, not the `id` column.  One via the `UNIQUE` column constraint, and the other via the explicit `CREATE INDEX`.